# Android Studio error at com.kami2017.app.MainActivity.onCreate

Tags: java, android, performance, error-handling, event-handling

```
Error:

02/01 14:12:04: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/Kamran/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.kami2017.app
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.kami2017.app"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.kami2017.app/com.kami2017.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2284 on device emulator-5554
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kami2017.app-1/lib/x86

          [ 02-01 14:12:28.511  1531: 1552 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x85a8d240, tid 1552
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.kami2017.app, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kami2017.app-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.kami2017.app, PID: 2284
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kami2017.app/com.kami2017.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
                      at com.kami2017.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference at com.kami2017.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)                                   Kindly Help me out........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not give any id for your WebView in xml file. You are trying to access that WebView.

FYI please look into following link:
[Getting void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl while loading webview in dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366792/getting-void-android-webkit-webview-loadurl-while-loading-webview-in-dialog-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

Your webview is null. Have you created an instance for the webview from your xml file in your activity?

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
```

Or you should create a new webview programmatically:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
```

Comment: where should i insert above code? kindly help me out.

Comment: Can you paste your code around MainActivity.java:17?
I 'll tell you which line